# Unable to call setVertexFillPaintTransformer - method is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, jung, jung2

I'm unable to run any of the Jung examples that set or change the Vertex (or other Transformers). I receive the following error:

```
The method setVertexFillPaintTransformer(Function) in the type RenderContext is not applicable for the arguments (Transformer<String,Paint>)
```

The sample code:

```
        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(vertexPaint);
```

where vertexPaint is

```
Transformer<String,Paint> vertexPaint = new Transformer<String,Paint>() {
           public Paint transform(String b) {
              return Color.orange;
           }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using version 2.1.* of the JUNG libraries (which uses the Guava types in place of the old common-collections-generics types such as Transformer: https://github.com/jrtom/jung/releases), but using an older version of the sample code.

If you use the version of the sample code that comes with 2.1.1, you should be fine.

Comment: I've found the samples and pulled down the latest git, but I'm unable to compile them - the most basic issue is that it seems to be getting confused - a typical error is "The constructor VisualizationViewer(Network, LayoutAlgorithm, Dimension) is undefined" - it looks like the code isn't using the right Jung version, even though I'm bringing in only Jung 2.1.1 libraries

Comment: I should mention that I'm adding the guava maven dependency, else it complains - <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>24.1-jre</version>
</dependency>

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535831/weird-import-issues-jung2 for an answer to the above concern.