# weird import issues - Jung2

Tags: jung, jung2

I've been trying to get Jung 2.1.1 to work successfully but whatever breaking changes were made are just not making sense.

After importing the 2.1.1 jars, I get the error:

```
The constructor VisualizationViewer(Network, LayoutAlgorithm, Dimension) is undefined
```

for the line:

```
VisualizationViewer vv = new 
            VisualizationViewer(g, layoutAlgorithm, new Dimension(900, 900));
```

where

```
 Network g = NetworkBuilder.undirected().build(); // and other load steps
```

There are other imports that aren't working, like

```
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.decorators.PickableNodePaintFunction;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.layout.LayoutAlgorithmTransition;
```

Edit: It appears the classes in the Jung 2.1.1 JAR still use the old definitions, for example

```
VisualizationViewer(Layout<V,E>,Dimension)
```

and not

```
VisualizationViewer(Network<N,E>,Dimension,Dimension)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered in https://github.com/jrtom/jung/issues/201

The short version is that you should not be cloning the HEAD version on the JUNG website; that's the 3.0 version in development, which is not yet ready for release, and is incompatible with 2.1.1.  Use the 2.1.1 version explicitly for both the jars and the samples.